# Replace URLs in JSON file using shell/bash or python?

Tags: python, json, regex, bash, parsing

I have a simple JSON file that we download from an artifactory that looks something like this:

**movie_list.json**

```
{
  "config": {
    "platform": {
      "api": "artifactory", 
      "url": "https://disney-europe.artifactory.com/myhome"
    }
  }, 
  "packages": {
    "platform": [
      "/netflix-australia/donkey_kong/random1.rpm", 
      "/netflix-australia/donkey_kong/random2.rpm"
    ]
  }
}
```

So basically, I need to read this JSON file and replace (remove Europe suffix):

`https://disney-europe.artifactory.com/myhome` with -> `https://disney.artifactory.com/myhome`

and (remove Australia suffix):

`/netflix-australia/donkey_kong/random1.rpm` with -> `/netflix/donkey_kong/random1.rpm`

Would this be easiest done with REGEX in python? or bash/shell?

I have used regex before in Java ,but not so much on .json files and on a Linux machine (this machine does have python installed so I can use that if its easier)

Thank you.

Comment: Do replace occur only at certain fields or every field? Are there only `europe` & `australia` needed to replaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I would suggest avoiding the use of REGEX. Since you know exactly the string you need to change, the KISS principle would suggest relying on the  `replace` method of strings since it is a less complicated approach.

```py
with open('old_file.txt', 'r') as infile:
    indata = infile.read()

# Replace the target string
formatted_data = indata.replace('disney-europe', 'disney').replace('netflix-australia', 'netflix')

# Write the file out again
with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
      outfile.write(formatted_data)
```

You could also overwrite the original file if you would rather not keep the original data hanging around.

However, since you specifically asked about using REGEX, you can do something like the following:

```py
import re

# Define what should be replaced
replacements = {"disney-europe": "disney", "netflix-australia": "netflix"} 
replacements = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in replacements.items()) 

# Replace any occurences in the file
pattern = re.compile("|".join(replacements.keys()))
with open('old_file.txt', 'r') as infile:
    indata = infile.read()

# This gives the new json data
formatted_data = pattern.sub(lambda m: replacements[re.escape(m.group(0))], indata)
```

Edit in response to comments:

The downside (in this case) to using REGEX is that you are taking on an additional layer of complexity to support additional features you don't need (i.e., REGEX pattern matching capabilities). This means you not only have to test your code against bugs in the control flow, but also agaisnt things like a malformed regular expression or unexpected text input. Overall it's more work and more to manage for little to no performance improvement.

Comment: I would just explain why you think a regex is bad here instead of showing how it can still be done

Answer (score 2):

Since you're dealing with JSON, you may wish to use jq; the benefit of that is it allows you to target exactly where in the JSON you want to make the change.

It really depends how well you know the data and how specific the changes you need to make are as to the best approach, but a simple example using jq might be:

```
$ cat your-data | jq '.config.platform.url |= if . == "https://disney-europe.artifactory.com/myhome" then "https://disney.artifactory.com/myhome" else . end | .packages.platform[] |= gsub("/netflix-australia/donkey_kong/";"/netflix/donkey_kong/")'
{
  "config": {
    "platform": {
      "api": "artifactory",
      "url": "https://disney.artifactory.com/myhome"
    }
  },
  "packages": {
    "platform": [
      "/netflix/donkey_kong/random1.rpm",
      "/netflix/donkey_kong/random2.rpm"
    ]
  }
}
```

You can chain as many transforms on as you want.

This example show an equality test and a pattern substitution, but jq has many other functions you may find better suited.